# How to mimic push notifications for ActivityKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-push-notifications, activitykit

I am trying to develop a Lock Screen widget that uses the ActivityKit. I will use APNs for updating the live activity. To update live activity, there are several fields in the header of push notification requests beside the aps object in payload. Several debug applications can mimic the push notification requests but there is no way to handle header fields for activityKit within these apps.

I think there may be a way to handle these requests from terminal. Are there any documentation or etc. for this issue?

EDIT:
I want to send request from my terminal to simulator.